# Unable to "npm install aws-lib"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-cognito

I am very new to AWS I started exploring AWS documentation and thought of connecting AWS sdk from NodeJS application for that I have installed npm aws-lib as follows.

**Can you please help me in this issue.**

> ```
> appss-MacBook-Pro-2:NodeJS apps$ npm install aws-lib
>
> aws-lib@0.3.0 node_modules/aws-lib
>
> ├── underscore@1.5.2 
> ├── xml2js@0.1.14
> └── sax@0.1.5
>
> appss-MacBook-Pro-2:NodeJS apps$ npm test
>
> npm ERR! Darwin 15.0.0
>
> npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "test"
>
> npm ERR! node v0.12.7
>
> npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
>
> npm ERR! path /Users/apps/Desktop/IOT/NodeJS/package.json
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT
>
> npm ERR! errno -2
>
> npm ERR! enoent ENOENT, open '/Users/apps/Desktop/IOT/NodeJS/package.json'
>
> npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>
> npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> npm ERR! enoent 
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>
> npm ERR!     /Users/apps/Desktop/IOT/NodeJS/npm-debug.log
>
> appss-MacBook-Pro-2:NodeJS apps$
> ```

**Output of `npm-debug.log` is as follows:**

> ```
> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>
> 1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'test' ]
>
> 2 info using npm@2.11.3
>
> 3 info using node@v0.12.7
>
> 4 verbose stack Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/apps/Desktop/IOT/NodeJS/package.json'
>
> 4 verbose stack     at Error (native)
>
> 5 verbose cwd /Users/apps/Desktop/IOT/NodeJS
>
> 6 error Darwin 15.0.0
>
> 7 error argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "test"
>
> 8 error node v0.12.7
>
> 9 error npm  v2.11.3
>
> 10 error path /Users/apps/Desktop/IOT/NodeJS/package.json
>
> 11 error code ENOENT
>
> 12 error errno -2
>
> 13 error enoent ENOENT, open '/Users/apps/Desktop/IOT/NodeJS/package.json'
>
> 13 error enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>
> 13 error enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> 14 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did install `aws-lib` just fine.  You can verify it by looking at `node_modules` directory in your project directory.

What you're doing next is calling `npm test` but it looks like you don't have `test` section in your `package.json` file, so `npm` doesn't know what to run for `test`.

Comment: Thanks now i got it.